# vuetify.js: v-form-textfield loaded with vue-router not visible

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm playing around with vuetify.js and having a problem.

I created a Component (Login in Login.vue) and it didn't show any text fields. So I tried it with one of the examples of the docs:

```
<template>
  <v-form v-model="valid">
    <v-text-field
      v-model="name"
      :rules="nameRules"
      :counter="10"
      label="Name"
      required
    ></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field
      v-model="email"
      :rules="emailRules"
      label="E-mail"
      required
    ></v-text-field>
  </v-form>
</template>

export default {
    data: () => ({
      valid: false,
      name: '',
      nameRules: [
        v => !!v || 'Name is required',
        v => v.length <= 10 || 'Name must be less than 10 characters'
      ],
      email: '',
      emailRules: [
        v => !!v || 'E-mail is required',
        v => /^\w+([.-]?\w+)*@\w+([.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(v) || 'E-mail must be valid'
      ]
    })
  }
```

I'm using webpacker for creating the final .js and .css files. vue-router is included by default and also some other stuff. The main.js:

```
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import {
  Vuetify,
  VApp,
  VNavigationDrawer,
  VFooter,
  VList,
  VBtn,
  VIcon,
  VGrid,
  VToolbar,
  VForm,
  transitions
} from 'vuetify'
import '../node_modules/vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  components: {
    VApp,
    VNavigationDrawer,
    VFooter,
    VList,
    VBtn,
    VIcon,
    VGrid,
    VToolbar,
    VForm,
    transitions
  },
  theme: {
    primary: '#ee44aa',
    secondary: '#424242',
    accent: '#82B1FF',
    error: '#FF5252',
    info: '#2196F3',
    success: '#4CAF50',
    warning: '#FFC107'
  }
})

Vue.use(Vuex);

/* eslint-disable no-new */
var vapp = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

The router is working fine and the Component's template is injected. There are no errors in the console and the inspector shows the template:

```
<form novalidate="novalidate"><v-text-field counter="10" label="Name" required=""></v-text-field> <v-text-field label="E-mail" required=""></v-text-field></form>
```

But the elements seem to have a height of 18px and a width of 0px. Even if I change their width I don't see anything and can't put my cursor inside.

Anyone has an idea what's going on here?
I first thought there might be a problem with packing the app.css - but including the default vuetify.css didn't solve anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import `VTextField` from vuetify in your `main.js` and add it to `components` part.

**Edit** : If you don't need `A la carte` component, and your app size doesn't matter juste use :

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify' 
Vue.use(Vuetify)
```

It will import everything from Vuetify.

[A la carte - Vuetify Documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/guides/a-la-carte)

Comment: damn. thought, VForm already contains the textfields and didn't look further. thanks! would've saved an hour